# Odoo `sudo` correct log

Tags: odoo

I am having problem using `sudo` in Odoo version 11. Checking doc, I think the same problem exists in version 12. Using `sudo` generate log with wrong(?) user. For e.g. I override `confirm_sale` to use `sudo`.

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    def action_confirm(self):
        return super(SaleOrder, self.sudo()).action_confirm()
```

Then let say when "Sale User" confirm sale order, log is shown as if "Administrator" approved sale order. Information is lost on who really confirmed sale order.

[image]

**Question:** So, my question is I want to use `sudo` but still record correctly who made changes.

**Clarification/Use Case:** Removing `sudo` and adding necessary permissions for user can solve the problem. But my very often use case is one group of users can only create/edit data and one or more groups can only confirm/approve data without edit permission. So, `sudo` is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this OCA module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/base_suspend_security/

Just install the module and use suspend_security() instead of sudo(), it will bypass access rights but keep the current user on log

Answer (score 1):

**Fixes:** Currently I am using the below fixes for this problem.

- Adding additional field to record who confirmed data.
- In Odoo 13, this feature is added. From doc, "The superuser mode does not change the current user, and simply bypasses access rights checks." https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#altering-the-environment